# data retrieval problem using PHP and Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have used jquery to post the data to a php validation page i have also got the result but when i get sucess i want to redirect to some other page(say success page) and on that page i want to display email-id.
   i have tried posting the data by using
        $.post('../success.php','$('#form')',function(data){
                alert(data);
        }) ;

to other page but when i write alert(data) i get the email-id in the alert box but it does not get displayed on the page.

success.php
   echo $_POST['email'];

Please Reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could submit a hidden form when the first ajax call returns success.

```
<form action="success.php" name="emailCallback" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="email" />
</form>

.success(function() { 
   $('form[name=emailCallback]').submit();
})
```